# npm package won't install on azure

Tags: git, azure, npm, vue.js, npm-install

I'm trying to deploy my site to azure, but npm install fails with the following error:

> 2498 silly fetchPackageMetaData error for
>   interactjs@git+https://github.com/taye/interact.js.git#v1.3.0-alpha.4
>   Command failed: D:\Program Files (x86)\Git\cmd\git.EXE submodule
>   update -q --init --recursive

This packages is actually a dependency to another package "vue-grid-layout", and is the only one that points to "git+https://github.com".

Trying to install only "vue-grid-layout" using `npm install vue-grid-layout` fails with the same error. I'm suspecting it has to do with the fact that the package does not point to the npm registry, but to github. It works locally though, and it also works on a different azure service app.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Disclaimer**: I'm the vue-grid-layout author.

Have you managed to fix that problem?

That dependency points to an alpha branch of interactjs, since I needed to use a fix on that lib that wasn't yet released. I'm actually planning to update to a newer version of interactjs and that would fix your problem: https://github.com/jbaysolutions/vue-grid-layout/issues/144

Comment: We had to download and reference the script directly. Not optimal, but it works. Looking forward to that new version! Thank you for making it